# Java app to open/register/sign up a new account on particular website?

Tags: java, forms, fill, account, auto-registration

I have spent 2 hours browsing this forum and other sources and still cannot find a basic solution - simple java code to fill an online registration form (only few fields) and submit it.

As an example I would use Amazon. Imagine my java app has only one button "Create Amazon Acc". User click on the button and a new amazon account has been registered. Amazon is not my actual target website but I can notice that there is same-level very basic form with few fields, no captcha, and the account gets opened immediately and the user is automatically loggen on.

[Direct link to the amazon reg form.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ap/register?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=gbflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.uk%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dnav_newcust)

I am only a java learner (University level) and just look for any ideas to implement my regNewAccount() method.

The full application will be used to make a quick order of an item at one particular online store. I want a small JFrame with one button "ORDER NOW", then input dialog "1st line of address" "postcode" "city" - which will register a new user account at that website and make an order so everything is done by one click. Possible???

Comment: For getting a specific and relevant answer, please consider posting your attempt. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You will need enter your data on the client browser and submit it to a Java application that is hosted on the Server.

Try looking into the GWT framework which essentially will help you create a Web application with the capability to submit data to a Java application on the Server.

If you are familiar with Java, it is relatively easy to pick this up.